# Macbook Pro reconnecting WLAN approx. every hour

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have two almost identical Macbooks Pro (MacBook Pros?) on my desk:

```
Macbook Pro 2019 with 10.15.7
Macbook Pro 2018 with 10.15.7
```

I have an expensive router with a very stable connection on all devices.

A few months ago, the 2018 MBP started to sporadically reconnect to the WLAN about once per hour, which is taking roughly 2 seconds to fulfill. No errors or problems, but the internet is gone for 1-2 seconds during that reconnect.

This happens even when actively using the notebook, no sleep mode or whatsoever involved.

It only happens on the 2018 Macbook, both have installed the same software.

Both are working on 5Ghz ac/Wi-Fi 5.
The problem is not due to DHCP lease resetting.

Is there any service running which could cause the reconnects?

Is there any option?

My router is not showing any problems with neither device but I have enabled verbose logging for now.

I'm currently running the Wireless Diagnostics in capturing mode and waiting for the next reset to happen.

**Update with verbose log from my router**

The router is showing a lot of entries like these:

```
12.01.21 19:45:53 New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 1300 Mbit/s, macbook, IP 192.168.178.1, MAC 38:x:x:...
12.01.21 19:45:51 Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), macbook, IP 192.168.178.1, MAC 38:x:x:...
```

**Update**

I'm still having that problem. I gave the Macbook to Apple, they wired a new keyboard and cover and checked all the cables between the antenna behind the display and the wlan interface on the pcb. They didn't find any hardware error. They returned the Macbook to me without the problem resolved.

```
02.08.21 | 14:59:00 | New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 1300 Mbit/s, macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 14:59:00 | Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 14:22:10 | New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 1300 Mbit/s, macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 14:22:08 | Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 13:51:12 | New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 1300 Mbit/s, macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 13:51:12 | Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 13:23:36 | New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 1300 Mbit/s, macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
02.08.21 | 13:23:36 | Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), macbook, IP 192.168.178.23, MAC 38:xxx.
```

Comment: Have you tried System Preferences > Network > WiFi: Delete that connection, then rejoin/login? That can often solve mysterious connection issues.

Comment: What evidence are you using to diagnose the dropouts as being related to the wifi?

Comment: From opening the question to now it reset 4 times, @karolus idea did not help :(

Comment: @Scottmeup The wifi symbol is making the animation of "looking for wifi" and "connecting" and its written when I click there

Comment: You _might_ have better luck on a stack with more of a focus on networking. Wireshark's packet capture can often give insight to what's happening but it's beyond my ability to make a diagnosis from a packet capture.